# How do I use the information from a record in a gridview to open up more details about that record in a new page in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a GridView table which links to my tblAssets table within SQL Server. I have a "View" hyperlink field which will link to the new page with the AssetID (PK) in the URL. I am wanting to use whichever AssetID is generated in the URL in a SQL View that I have created - I got close whereby clicking on the "View" field will redirect to the page and have the correct URL but will return everything from the SQL View. So I tried to change the SelectCommand but it returned an error.

This is my .aspx code for the GridView:

```
  <form id="frmAssets" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssetManagementConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAssets]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="AssetID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" 
BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4"
 Font-Names="Segoe UI" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" style="font-weight: 700" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" Font-Size="Small">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BorderStyle="None" Font-Overline="False" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="AssetID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="AssetDetails.aspx?AssetID={0}" Text="View" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Asset_Tag" HeaderText="Asset Tag" SortExpression="Asset_Tag" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Asset_Type" HeaderText="Asset Type" SortExpression="Asset_Type" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial_Number" HeaderText="Serial_Number" SortExpression="Serial_Number" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="300px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="DepartmentID" SortExpression="DepartmentID" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
```

Apologies for the poor embedding.

This is the .aspx code for the page which it redirects to (I'm assuming I need to change the SelectCommand but can't get it working:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Asset Tag" HeaderText="Asset Tag" SortExpression="Asset Tag" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Manufacturer" HeaderText="Manufacturer" SortExpression="Manufacturer" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Model" SortExpression="Model" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssetManagementConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAssets]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: What was the error? Have you tried adding ` WHERE AssetID = <your asset id>` to the `SelectCommand`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SelectParameters` from http get query to the detail select query

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AssetManagementConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblAssets] WHERE AssetID = @AssetID">
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField ="AssetID" Name="AssetID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.